# Js+ how to send data parameters with blob to servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I have this following js code to send an audio file to servlet. I need to send two more additional parameters to the servlet. Following is my current code

```
form = new FormData(),
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
form.append("file",blob, filename);
request.open(
        "POST",
        "AudioToText",
        true
    );
request.send(form);
```

CAn anyone help me with js code how to add additional two parameters like id/pass in this request and how to fetch them in the servlet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The second param in request.open() suppose to point to the file that will process the data in absolute an absolute link, there's also another property of the XMLHttpRequest type called onreadystatechanged which expects a callback that will check to see whether or not the request was successful

Example Code - ignore the lines with self, this those are just variables pointing to methods/properties and are not dependent to perform a request:

```
        // if an Object to connect to server was created begin transfer
        if (this.xhr) {

            var processData = function () {
                // if everything is ok carry on
                if (self.xhr.readyState === 4 && self.xhr.status === 200) {
                    if(self.responseType === "text"){
                        self.Success(self.xhr.responseText);
                    }else{
                        self.Success(self.xhr.responseXML);
                    }
                }
                // if something fails along the way else execute failure method
                else if (self.xhr.status !== 200 && self.xhr.readyState === 4) {
                // something went wrong
                }
            };


            // open connection
            this.xhr.open(this.method, this.host, true);


            // set up the connection to a method to process the data
            //noinspection JSPrimitiveTypeWrapperUsage
            this.xhr.onreadystatechange = processData;

            // send the data
            this.xhr.send(this.postData);
```

Comment: My quesry is little bit different. I want to send a file(blob) and two parameters (userid and password) in one servlet call.

Comment: To save the file in the server I need to know the userid and password from the UI. So file, userid and password have to send to servlet from javascript in one call

Comment: Then append the user's ID and their password to the ajax call. If the user logs in you can store their user ID in a cookie and have javascript fetch it and add it the ajax call as a parameter (which will be in your FormData object)... If your each user has a unique ID you won't need to send their password as u can query it on the server side based on their ID